# Create a "Collection of Collections" in jQuery

Tags: jquery, collections

I have some HTML roughly like this:

```
<div id="x">
   <div class="equal-height"></div>
   <div class="equal-height"></div>
   <div class="equal-height"></div>
</div>

<div>
   <div id="y>
      <div class="equal-height"></div>
      <div class="equal-height"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I'm not sure if this is possible but I would like to create a jQuery expression that would return a "collection of collections". In my example, there would be a single "outer collection" with two elements. The first element is a collection of the 3 `div` elements nested in `<div id="x">` while the second element is a collection of the two `div` elements within `<div id="y">`.

To put it another way, I want a collection of all the collections of the sibling `<div class="equal-height">` elements. I can think of a general approach but it's not pretty.

I don't care if the resulting collection is a jQuery collection of an array of arrays.

**I should have made it clear in my original post that I do not want to hard-code "x" and "y" ids. I just want all the parents of `class="equal-height"` along with the `equal-height` children themselves.**

Answer (score 3):

There isn't any built-in jQuery method to do what you're asking as all jQuery objects are flat lists of objects, not 2D arrays.

The simplest thing I can think of for a general purpose answer that works with `.equal-height` elements anywhere in your document is to get all the `.equal-height` elements and then split them into sub-arrays by examining the parent:

```js
var result = [];
$(".equal-height").each(function(index, element) {
    if (!result.length || element.parentNode !== result[result.length - 1][0].parentNode) {
        result.push([element]);
    } else {
        result[result.length - 1].push(element);
    }
});

// display results
document.write("[" + result.map(function(item) {
  return JSON.stringify(item.map(function(obj) {
    return obj.id;
  }));
}) + "]");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="x">
   <div id="a" class="equal-height"></div>
   <div id="b" class="equal-height"></div>
   <div id="c" class="equal-height"></div>
</div>

<div>
   <div id="y">
      <div id="d" class="equal-height"></div>
      <div id="e" class="equal-height"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

And, here's another scheme that gets a list of the unique parent elements and then for each parent, builds a list of the children that match the selector:

```js
var result = $('.equal-height').parent().get().map(function(item) {
    return $(item).children(".equal-height").get();
});

// display results
document.write("[" + result.map(function(item) {
  return JSON.stringify(item.map(function(obj) {
    return obj.id;
  }));
}) + "]");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="x">
   <div id="a" class="equal-height"></div>
   <div id="b" class="equal-height"></div>
   <div id="c" class="equal-height"></div>
</div>

<div>
   <div id="y">
      <div id="d" class="equal-height"></div>
      <div id="e" class="equal-height"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

---

If you want to hard code knowledge of the `x` and `y` elements as the parent elements, you can simply do this:

```
var result = [$("#x .equal-height").get(), $("#y .equal-height").get()];
```

Or the same concept could be written like this:

```
var result = ["#x", "#y"].map(function(item) {
    return $(item + " .equal-height").get();
});
```

Comment: get() returns DOM Node with vanilla interface, in my variant it returns jquery collection :) Maybe some variant with reduce?

Comment: @LarionovNikita - Since the OP was not very specific about what a collection or collections is supposed to be exactly and jQuery does NOT know how to process an array of arrays inside a jQuery object or an array of jQuery objects inside a jQuery object, I figured I would go safe and just make an array of arrays of DOM objects since you can't use jQuery directly on the result anyway.  But, obviously any of my options can be tweaked to adjust the format of the output as desired if they wanted an array of jQuery objects for example.

Comment: Yes you absolutely right. There are no methods to work with array of jquery collections. DOM Nodes can be wrapped again in $. Your solution is much more safe.

Comment: @tombaxter - I added a second option that does not hard code the #x and #y knowledge.

Comment: @tombaxter - I added ids to each equal-height element so it's easier to display the results in the snippets.

Answer (score 1):

`var containers = $('.equal-height').parent();`

If I'm understanding you, you're just approaching it the wrong way. the `parent` jQuery helper should do the trick.

The selector will select the elements you want encapsulated, so that you can get to the container divs via `parent`. Once you have the parent divs, you can call `containers.children()` to get the collection of children.

Comment: That's not quite what I was looking for. With your approach I would have to then have to iterate over each parents' children, selecting those with `class="equal-height"`. But overall, this is not a bad approach. Thanks you.

Comment: For that: `var tmp = containers.children('.equal-height')` :p

Comment: Or more verbosely, if you wanted to group by parent and work with each set:

`containers.each(function (index, element) { var subset = $(element).children('.equal-height'); });`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hard-code the input properties, you can use map with array.

```
var childSelector = '.equal-height';

function getSubCollection(id) {
  return $('#' + id).find(childSelector);
}
var collectionOfCollection = ['x', 'y'].map(getSubCollection);
console.log(collectionOfCollection);
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a variety of jquery and css selectors that you can use to select different sections of your code.

In order to select all collections based on id's, you would do something like this, with unlimited amount of commas separating the id's you wish to select.

```
var collections = $("#x,#y");
```

this would select your x div and your y div, not including their children.

To select their **direct** children, you would do this:

```
var collections = $("#x,#y").children(); //or to select only their direct div children:
var collections = $("#x > div, #y > div");
```

To select **all** of their descendants (their children's children and so on), you would do this:

```
var collections = $("#x *,#y *"); //or to select all of their div descendants:
var collections = $("#x div, #y div");
```

You can also use your class to select the items that have your class, like this (this will select the items you specified in your class that are children of the divs with ids x and y):

```
var collections = $("#x .equal-height, #y .equal-height");
```

You can edit all of these, like changing their background color like this:

```
collections.css("background-color","blue");
```

With all these different selectors (and more), I don't see why you would need an array you just got to know what you want to select so that afterwards you can edit that portion. There are ways to filter the children by their type,id, class, attributes, index of child, etc.

I hope this helped, here's a link of Jquery selectors:

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp

EDIT: to get both the parents and the div children:

```
var collections = $("#x,#y,#x .equal-height, #y .equal-height");
```

this will assign to collections all of the items, yet not in an orderly fashion which is what I think your question is.

Comment: I don't see anything in this answer that creates a collection of collections.  Also, note the OP now clarifies that they do not want to hard code #x or #y.